# Devise and Lazy Signup / Gradual Engagement password requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise

I'm trying to implement gradual engagement with Devise as described here in Rails 3:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up

At the first step:

```
%h2 Sign up. All we need is your email address.   =
   semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>
   user_registration_path(resource)) do |form|
   = devise_error_messages!
   = form.inputs do
```

> ```
>   = form.input :email, :input_html => {:autofocus => true}
> = form.actions do
>   = form.action :submit, :label => "Sign up"   = render 'shared/links'
> ```

I run into a "password cannot be blank" problem.

Under User.validators:

```
#<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fe53fe264f0 @attributes=[:password],
```

but I do not have any validator for password in my user.rb file. Is this standard behavior for Devise?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

The tutorial didn't mention configuring Devise beforehand. How should I fix this to allow for lazy engagement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this method in `user.rb`

```
  def password_required?
    if !persisted?
      false
    else
      !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
    end
  end
```